# How to find the shallow copied row on DevExtreme DataGrid?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, devextreme, devextreme-angular

I am using angularjs/devextreme datagrid in my project where i am coopying existing row into new row using angular.merge (1.x) mehtod.

```
addNewRow() {
   //Find current row    
   let row = gridGetSelectedRowsDataAll( this.customerGridContainer );   
   var newRow = angular.merge( {}, this.customerGridData[rowIndex] ); //SHALLOW COPY the row.        
   this.saveRow(newRow, rowIndex );
}
```

After i copy the existing row to new row then i lost scope of the new row, but i want to process some data transformation logic only on the copied row of records. How can i achieve this? I need to find out if the particular row is copied and then perform some operation. How can i achieve this?

```
   processRow()
   { 
    if(row.newRow) ???
    }
```

Comment: In my project the new row has a formgroup with editable fields. When I copy/paste between them I write to this formGroup (which is only visible when editing).

Comment: Maybe do a better job of keeping track of the copy?